# AsyncTask not actually async

Tags: android

I have a threading issue. When I try to write in TextView percentage of successful download, it doesn't update it at all, until the end (until all content received) and it just show 100 at the end.

Seems like it is not actually running in another thread...

I tried to use logging in console instead of using **publishProgress**, and it works. It seems like **MainActivity** is frozen until the download task is done.

```
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int count = 0;
            int size = 0;

            while (reader.read() != -1) {
                size++;
            }

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;

                int progress = (int) (((float) count++ / (float) size) * 100);
                publishProgress(progress);

                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        textView.setText((values[0]).toString());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.text);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;

    try {
        result = task.execute("https://stackoverflow.com/").get();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("Contents Of URL", result);
}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the get method in the ASyncTask, as per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

That means you told the async task to run sincronously.

To have it running async, don't use the get method.

```
task.execute("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

And use the onPostExecute to retrieve the result:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

 }
```

Comment: Just to clarify for OP: The `onPostExecute` method needs to be declared in `DownloadTask`. It can do the logging there and, if desired, call back to a method in the `Activity` class to do further processing (or it can update the UI directly, since `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread).